# SQL Server View tables not joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am incredibly new to SQL and am trying to create a view for a pizza store database. The sides ordered table and the sides names table have to be separate but need a view that combines them.

This is the code I have entered,

```
CREATE VIEW ordered_sides_view 
AS
    SELECT 
        ordered_side_id, side.side_id, side_name, number_ordered, 
        SUM(number_ordered * price) AS 'total_cost'
    FROM 
        ordered_side 
    FULL JOIN 
        side ON ordered_side.side_id = side.side_id
    GROUP BY 
        ordered_side_id, side.side_id, side_name, number_ordered;
```

The problem is that this is the resulting table.

Screenshot of view table:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I get the names to match the ordered sides?

Comment: Try to change the full join to an inner join.

Comment: Zohar, Thank you for your comment. I just tried your suggestion but now nothing is showing in the table at all.

Comment: Well, in that case, please edit your question to include sample data (as DDL+DMl - meaning create table and insert into statements) and desired results. That will enable us to give you the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You fail to understand what a `FULL JOIN` and an `INNER JOIN` operation does.

- `FULL JOIN` returns at least every row from each table (plus any extra values from the `ON` clause).
- `INNER JOIN` returns only matching row sets based on the `ON` clause.
- `OUTER JOIN` returns every matching row set PLUS the side of the join that the `OUTER JOIN` is on (`LEFT OUTER JOIN` vs `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`).

In your picture, you can clearly see that there are no rows that match from the tables `ordered_side` and `side`...

[image: Problem Query]

That is why switching to an INNER JOIN returns zero rows...there are no matches on the **COLUMNS YOU CHOSE TO USE**.

Why in your SELECT operator do you have this:

```
SELECT ordered_side_id, side.side_id, side_name, number_ordered,
```

while your ON clause has this:

```
side ON ordered_side.side_id = side.side_id
```

ordered_side_id !=ordered_side.side_id

Investigate your columns and fix your `JOIN` clause to match the correct columns.

> P.S. I like how you structure your queries. Very nice and what an
>   expert does! It makes reading MUCH, MUCH easier. :)
>
> One suggestion I might add is structure your columns in the SELECT statement in its own row:

```
SELECT ordered_side_id
     , side.side_id
     , side_name
     , number_ordered
     , SUM(number_ordered * price) AS Total_Cost --or written [Total_Cost]/'Total_Cost'
FROM ordered_side
FULL JOIN side ON ordered_side.ordered_side_id = side.side_id
GROUP BY ordered_side_id
       , side.side_id
       , side_name
       , number_ordered;
```